# Сайт не работает без VPN

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

К сожалению, заметил, что сайт без VPN просто не загружается. Пробовал из Firefox, Chrome, Yandex, даже с Android'а - все равно не грузится. В связи нарастающими репрессиями насчет Telegram говорю - да, я пользователь данного мессенджера - может, SE сотрудничает с Google, который уже заблокировал мой IP? Или дело в другом? Могу сказать только одно - из моей сети ruSO не грузится никакими методами, кроме VPN. Были ли у кого-нибудь подобные проблемы и с чем они могут быть связаны?

P. S. При работе без Virtual Private Network браузер долго настраивает соединение, а затем выводит следующую страницу:
[image: Скриншот]

Comment: У меня `404` на всех страницах всех сайтов stackexchange, а на главных страницах `windows server` заглушка, если прокси не использовать.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin, так надо что-то делать, иначе поток посетителей спадет, и сайт уйдет в тартары. Кстати, Вы `Telegram` использовали?

Comment: судя по всему, проблема у вашего провайдера, которого за это надо нещадно тормошить

Comment: @etki, провайдер мой - зло. Это компания Virgin Connect, жутко продажная и дешевая. К сожалению, выбора нет. До блокировки телеги все работало нормально, а сейчас многие сайты недоступны. Жаль.

Comment: Заглушка `IIS` повисела минут 20 и всё опять стало ровно. Провайдер очень малоизвестный, обслуживает пару БЦ в Питере.

Comment: Пробил IP-адреса за доменом по боту-проверяльщику (в Телеграме, хе-хе): нет, ни один из четырёх адресов **не числится в списках блокировки**. Не думаю, что бот обновляется сильно медленнее провайдеров.

Comment: @D-side, несмотря на это, у меня ruSO не работает уже неделю (если, конечно, не использовать костыли типа прокси или VPN).

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский у меня (в Петербурге) уже давно (год?) не работает archive.org, хотя никакие реестры его не указывают как заблокированный; ни его, ни его IP-адреса. (Раз уж вспомнил, звоню провайдеру узнать в чём дело.)

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский абсолютно неважно продажный провайдер или нет. Если в договоре нет пункта "клиент согласен, что мы когда угодно что угодно можем блокировать" и ip-адреса серверов SO нет в списках РКН, то пишите в техподдержку провайдера, а в случае отсутствия реакции в Роспотребнадзор и Роскомнадзор.

Comment: @D-side ссыль на бота?

Comment: @teran любой из секции "Оперативная информация" на [мониторинге блокировок](https://usher2.club/).

Answer (score 2):

У меня через раз появляется плашка "Скрипт со стороннего домена заблокирован или недоступен".
Проблема в недоступности [Google APIs](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js), а точнее - библиотеки jQuery, отсутствие которой ломает всё.
Непонятно почему не сделать fallback.
Из-за чего не работает меню/скрипт входа/что-то ещё наверняка.

Comment: Нет, там конкретно не работает сам сайт.

Comment: Я понял. Просто к вопросам о блоках написал.

Comment: У меня такое же бывает.

Answer (score 2):

В общем, провайдер на данный счет не высказал никаких комментариев. Однако сайт вчера заработал!